# Replacing less than value with NA across multiple fields using dplyr

Tags: dplyr, pipe

I am working with a dataframe with responses to survey questions (recorded as a dichotomous binary variable). I want to stratify answers to one survey question by their answer to a demographic question. For privacy reasons, I would like to suppress any answer (from 0, 1, and NA) where <5 participants responded.

I've wrote code using dplyr that works for the crosstab, but I cannot do the data suppression steps as part of my piping command. I'm including my code and example current and desired output tables here, does anyone have suggestions?

```
crosstab.demo <- df %>% 
  select(c(answer_var, demo_var)) %>%
  group_by(answer_var) %>%
  count(demo_var) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = answer_var, values_from = n)
```

current output table, where NA is due to skipping the survey question.

| demo_var | 0 | 1 | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| demo1 | 76 | 182 | 47 |
| demo2 | 378 | 717 | 210 |
| demo3 | 3 | 9 | 2 |
| demo4 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| NA | 23 | 29 | 13 |

Desired output

| demo_var | 0 | 1 | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| demo1 | 76 | 182 | 47 |
| demo2 | 378 | 717 | 210 |
| demo3 | NA | 9 | NA |
| demo4 | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | 23 | 29 | 13 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your end table, you can use `across()` inside `mutate()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
read.table(header=T, text="
demo_var    0   1   NA
demo1   76  182 47
demo2   378 717 210
demo3   3   9   2
demo4   4   2   1
NA  23  29  13") %>% 
  mutate(across(-demo_var, ~ifelse(.x<=5, NA, .x)))
#>   demo_var  X0  X1 NA.
#> 1    demo1  76 182  47
#> 2    demo2 378 717 210
#> 3    demo3  NA   9  NA
#> 4    demo4  NA  NA  NA
#> 5     <NA>  23  29  13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As we don't have access to `df`, it is difficult to give the best answer. For your future questions, please provide your dataset using `dput(df)`.

Therefore, this code might also work, although I cannot test it:

```
crosstab.demo <- df %>% 
  select(c(answer_var, demo_var)) %>%
  group_by(answer_var) %>%
  count(demo_var) %>%
  mutate(n=ifelse(n<=5, NA, n) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = answer_var, values_from = n)
```